# OpenTelemetry Service Point not showing in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry

I installed OpenTelemetry operator in Kubernets. Installed it using helm.

```
helm install my-opentelemetry-collector open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector
```

Below is the ConfigMap of collector

```
 prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: opentelemetry-collector
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - ${MY_POD_IP}:8888
```

How can I add OpenTelemetry collector target to prometheus

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure also [prometheus exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusremotewriteexporter) in your metrics pipeline.